# Android: creating custom 2D avatar

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout, offset, avatar

I am creating an app that allows a user to build a custom 2D avatar by specifying things like shoes, socks, skin color, etc...

Currently my solution has been to create a .PNG of each item and then to 'stack' them all on top of each other in a RelativeLayout.  So for example, I create an ImageView of two shoes and align the ImageView to the center of the relative layout and the bottom of the Relative Layout.  Next I 'stack' the bottom edge of the socks to the top edge of the shoe.  And on and on.

This method works, but I feel like I don't have much control over where the parts sit and would much rather be able to calculate the x,y coordinates at run time and place the images that way.  For instance, this works well if all of the ImageViews are stacked, but if I need to place one ImageView 10 pixels below the top edge of another ImageView I can't do it (or at least I haven't figured out how yet).

**I am looking for a solution that will allow me to control the x,y position of ImageViews and allow ImageView to be offset from each other.**

Comment: Did you find any solution ... or any library thats doing this? overall avatar creation?

Comment: No.  I ended up creating a custom view and basically coming up with some rules on how the avatar was assembled.  So shoes were always the lowest item on the screen. Legs attached to the shoes. Torso always attached to the top of the legs, etc...  Then at runtime I would measure the height of each components (legs, torso, etc...) and assign its position so the character looked correct.  For instance, if legs were 200 px tall, then the bottom of the torso would be positioned to x = x, y = 200.  I was pretty new to programming when I tried this and I am sure there is probably a better way.

Comment: emm.. i m not very new to programming, but i m thinking almost same thing.. so you have a pallet of items, I will keep fix calculation for each image.. let say what part of cap is center from head.. so if user select that hat/cap.. it will appear on head of cartoon character... probably i will come-up with some good data structure to make it scalable for many items.. but basic logic is same.

so no libraries out there? I see your question is already one year old.

Comment: Perhaps the method I described for positioning the components of the avatar is sound, but my implementation at the time was pretty poor.  I haven't searched for any avatar creation libraries so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather place the images by x,y coordinates, then you should consider using a single view and simply drawing the images on top. See this [doc on custom drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html). You'll find [`drawBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) and some of its overloads useful.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I believe that is what I've been searching for.